# Creating N number of individual delete forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to write a forum-like application where users can add comments (saved in database) and attach up to 3 files to each comment.

```
    // SQL query to SELECT comments from database
   
    // Echo out all comments
    foreach ($resultCom as $row) {
        echo $commentContent;

    // Echo out up to 3 files for each comment
                    if (isset($commentFile1) {
                        echo "<a class='file-download' href='upload/$commentFile1'>$commentFileName1</a>";
                        }
                        if (isset($commentFile2) {
                        echo "<a class='file-download' href='upload/$commentFile2'>$commentFileName2</a>";
                        }
                        if (isset($commentFile3) {
                        echo "<a class='file-download' href='upload/$commentFile3'> $commentFileName3</a>";
                        }
}
```

Now I want to give the user the possibility to delete each of the files in their comment which means I need to write a delete form for each file in each comment:

```
<form action="delete_file.php" method="post">
  <input name="id">
  <input name="filename">
...
<button type="submit" name="delete-submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

This same `<form>` would exist many times, using the same `name` attributes for inputs/submit buttons. If I use JavaScript to loop through every file and give each input field an unique name, I would still end up having one button that submits the information to my `action="delete_file.php"` which is then caught and processed in delete_file.php with something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete-file-submit'])) { delete files/update database}
```

I've tried a couple of approaches and each of them failed. A hint how I would set up a delete form for each of the files using their unique attributes (filename, file id, etc.) would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: learn ajax, then upon clicking the delete link it makes a request to delete the uploaded file, using a form will cause the users browser to reload etc

Comment: in the meantime, while you're learning ajax, why can't you just create the forms in php when you render the link and then set the input `value` attribute to the value of the current file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it. Is to use an AJAX, but if this must be in PHP here you go:

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_POST['filename'])) {

        $name = $_POST['filename'];
        $id= $_POST['id'];
        
        //Direction where you store your files
        $target_dir = "/";

        // If u store it by name then do this:
        $target_file = $target_dir . $name;

        // If you store it by id then do this:
        // $target_file = $target_dir . $id; 

        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            if(unlink($target_file)){
                echo "File". $name ." was removed.";

             }else{
                echo "Error!". $name . "was not removed";
            }   
        }else{
            echo "Could not find file". $name;
        }
    }
?>
```

Of course it depends how do you store your data, but if it is in this same directory this is the way.

AJAX function would like like this, but you have to do some changes to fit it in your code:

```
const deleteFiles = (id, filename) => {
    
    //Ask if your user wants to delete file
    let confirmDelete =  confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + filename + "?");

    //If yes, its doing this
    if(confirmDelete){
        $.post("php/deleteFile.php",
            {
                id: id,
                filename: filename
            },
            function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

My idea is to create strucutre of element like this:

```
<div data-name="name" data-id="id">
     <a>IMAGE HERE</a>
     <button class="delete-file">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

Then search for every element with class .delete-file and set on it listener for click like this:

```
document.find(".deleteFile").click(function(){
    deleteFile(this.parent().dataset.id, this.parent().dataset.name);
});
```

If you will have any problems, or dont undestand sth, let me now.

Small edit: As it was said in comments, you will need additional sanitazer for your filename to stay safe, without injections. Here is the simple one (if you will need more advanced one, you should look for it in web) :

```
$name = mb_ereg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;\[\]\(\).])", '', $name );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I like how clean the AJAX answer looks, so I'll definitely look into that after trying the php solution!

Comment: `"Are you sure you want to delete " + name + "?"`  ... I think you mean `filename`?  I have security concerns about your advice.  What happens when bad dudes start putting dots in the filepath and carry on deleting files that they should? Time to put your sanitizing gloves on.  Food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my mistake and for sure you need sanitazing here, i forgot about mentioning that, but i belive that @sojutyp would remember bout this or would create good storing data system.